# Web API 2 filtering based on a company

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I am using .NET web api 2 with entity framework 6 and I new to this thing.I have a B2B based system and tables store data for different companies.

When I implemented Users api for my project, it is returning all the users. Similarly I have to get the menus based on a single company only.Is there a way to add a global filter either in web api 2 or ER 6 , so that everything in response is based on the company id for which the application is running.I am storing data for all companies in single database.

Lets say web site is deployed for company X, so every api call will return data only for that company.I do not want to them to see users of other company or menus of other companies.

I hope that the question is clear to you.

Comment: Sounds like you need a business layer in the middle. If you were following repository, for eg, you'd have `ICompanySpecificRepository : IRepository` which would apply a filter to every entity for you.

Comment: @BradChristie can you please explain me more.You mean I need repo for each company? dont you think thats an over kill.I have models classes and DTOs.

Comment: Doesn't have to be respository,just some middle layer that supplies context.  Basically, with every db call it's already filtered out items relevant to the company.